# Using a form_for to create a nested model row

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

- Each "User" has one "Move".
- Each "Move" has many "Neighborhood Preferences".

I want to create a form on the "/user/(:id)/edit" page that lets a person edit their "move", and "neighborhood_preferences".

Currently, the form displays correctly. But when I submit the form, I get this error `Move(#2168853040) expected, got ActionController::Parameters(#2158484920)`.

How can I save both a new move, and the neighborhood_preferences?

View for Users#edit

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag "user[move][neighborhood_ids][]", nil %>

  <% @neighborhoods.each do |n| %>
    <%= check_box_tag "user[move][neighborhood_ids][]", 
        n.id, # the value to submit
        @user.move.neighborhood_ids.include?(n.id), # Check the box on load 
        id: dom_id(n) # add a unique category based on the object
    %>
    <%= label_tag dom_id(n), n.name %>
    <br/>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit "Save Changes" %>
<% end %>
```

Controller for Users#edit

```
def edit
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @neighborhoods = Neighborhood.all
end



private 
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(
        :email, 
        :age,
        :gender,
        :university,
        :grad_year,
        :occupation,
        :company,
        # Allow form to submit neighborhood_ids for a user's move.
        move: [neighborhood_ids: []]
      )
    end
```

Models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attr_accessible :provider, :uid, :name, :email
  validates_presence_of :name
  has_one :move
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :move, allow_destroy: true


class Move < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :neighborhood_preferences
    has_many :neighborhoods, through: :neighborhood_preferences
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :neighborhood_preferences, allow_destroy: true
end

class NeighbhoodPreference < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :neighborhood
  belongs_to :move
end
```

Comment: Have you looked into `accepts_nested_attributes_for`?  I think that is what you want. http://currentricity.wordpress.com/2011/09/04/the-definitive-guide-to-accepts_nested_attributes_for-a-model-in-rails-3/ You'll need to do things a little different with Rails4 because of the way it handles StrongParams but that should get you started.

Comment: Thanks @mrrogers - I actually included that in my models - pasted the model code above as well

Comment: You can use `fields_for` in your form view code to leverage that - http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for